# using the same uitableview to reload data and use back button

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

Dont know how else to explain this but basically im using a uitableview to load data(core data) and have basically limitless lists and items. for instance list1 is food contains candy, starches, meat, and meat may contain beef, chicken, etc. if i click through the tableviews and get to chicken, how do i use the back button to go back to previous. I am just using "reload data" instead of multiple tableviews in storyboard. is there a better way to do this???

I started to set 3 values prevparentlist, subparentlist, and parentlist. but end up losing prevparentlist when you go to deep and it will only back up one level....didnt think this through.....please help

Comment: use table view in tags

Comment: So instead of pushing a new view controller, you want to remain on the same view controller but update the tableView to show only the selected type of item ?

Comment: this is correct. as of right now it just uses a fetch with predicate and pulls that data and reloads the current uitableview. it is basically a custom app to where when the user clicks the "add" button it gives them the option of adding a list or an item. so it would technically have infinite amount of uitableviews. so am i suppose to make 500 tableviews in storyboard?? surely there is an easier way to handle this

Answer (score 0):

You just don't easily "reuse" tableViews.

If the storyboard gets too messy in your opinion the best way is creating a custom viewController (including XIB), set the original `NSManagedObjectContext` to it (as property) and also provide a `NSPredicate` which meets your criteria.

Then you'll push that viewController into your navigation stack.

ARC will take care of releasing the viewController and corresponding view if you setup the properties correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be easily solved , you have to keep and int value and that keeps on increasing with table view did select and which will decrease on pressing back button. Depending on the int value you can load the table view data.